# How to display column names in every row in the table?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to display column names in every row in the table. I am using Bootstrap for a clear look. How can I do it?

**wp.html**

```
<body>
  <div class="container p-5  ">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="main" class="col-xs-7 col-lg-8">
            <table class="table table-borderless">
                <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th scope="col">Vehicle</th>
                    <th scope="col">Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Route</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>AIN 4525</td>
                    <td>QHSE</td>
                    <td>12:03pm</td>
                    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                </tr><tr>
      ...
</body>
```

This is what I want:

[image: Table Example]

Comment: Are you manually typing this code out, or generating it with something like javascript or php?

Comment: I typed manually

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to type the header in each cell then like so, and you can use spans to style them:

```
<tr>
    <td><span class='cellHeader'>Vehicle</span><br>AIN 4525</td>
    <td><span class='cellHeader'>Type</span><br>QHSE</td>
    <td><span class='cellHeader'>Data</span><br>12:03pm</td>
    <td><span class='cellHeader'>Route</span><br>Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr><tr>
```

Then just add some css to style the `cellHeader` class to look how you want (like gray text).